# Google map onClick event inside fragment class

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have a `mapview` inside a `fragment` along with other UI components. When I click on map I want to open a new activity instead of zooming map in this view. Zooming should work on the new activity. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use setAllGesturesEnabled(). This will disable pinching and panning.
Please see documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setAllGesturesEnabled(boolean)):

As for handling a click event on map, see documentation for `OnMapClickListener` [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#map_clicklong_click_events):

Inside the listener, you may start a new activity with another map view that is zoom-able.